# Prove an identity regarding an integral operator

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

Let $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be continous and define the operator $T$ in the following way

$$Tf(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^x \frac{f(t)}{\sqrt{x-t}} \, \text{d}t \, . $$

(i) Prove $Tf$ is continuous on $[0,1]$.

(ii) Prove that
$$T^2f(x)= \int_0^xf(t)\,\text{d}t\,, \ \ \ \forall x \in [0,1]\,. $$

I think I got the first part, using the limit under the integral sign theorem. However, I am stuck on part (ii).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

\begin{align}
T^2f(x) &= T(Tf)(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^x \frac{Tf(t)}{\sqrt{x-t}}\, dt\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{x-t}} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^t \frac{f(u)}{\sqrt{t-u}}\, du\, dt\\
&= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^x f(u)\, du \int_u^x (x - t)^{-1/2}(t -u)^{-1/2}\, dt\tag{*}\\
\end{align}

By the change of variable $v = x - t$,

$$\int_u^x (x - t)^{-1/2}(t - u)^{-1/2}\, dt = \int_0^{x - u} v^{-1/2}(x - u - v)^{-1/2}\, dv$$

By the change of variable $v = (x - u)w$,

$$\int_0^{x-u} v^{-1/2}(x - u - v)^{-1/2}\, dv = \int_0^1 w^{-1/2}(1 - w)^{-1/2}\, dw$$

Show that $\int_0^1 w^{-1/2}(1 - w)^{-1/2}\, dw = \pi$. Then (*) becomes $\int_0^x f(u)\, du$.

Answer (score 1):

Another kind of answer.

Put first $f_m(t)=t^m$, where $m$ is a real $\geq 0$. Then using the change of variable $t=ux$ we get easily that $T(f_m)(x)=c_m x^{m+1/2}$, with
 $$\sqrt{\pi}c_m= \int_0^1 u^m(1-u)^{-1/2}du=B(m+1,1/2)=\Gamma(m+1)\Gamma(1/2)/\Gamma(m+3/2)$$

Hence 
 $$T^2(f_m)=(m+1)c_mc_{m+1/2}\int_0^x f_m(t)dt$$
 It is easy to see  (using $\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt{\pi}$) that $(m+1)c_mc_{m+1/2}=1$. Hence we get the formula for all $f_m$, and by linearity for all $f\in \mathbb{R}[x]$. But as $T^2$ and $G$ defined by $G(f)(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt$ are continous function of $f$, and $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is dense in $C([0,1], \mathbb{R})$, we have the equality for all $f$.